# Calculate total area of features in different categories in attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a vector layer which includes the acreage of the different features, I want to calculate the sum acreage of all polygons with

Parcel size >400 acres
Parcel size <100acres
Parcel size >100acres
Parcel size > 1000acres

[image: screenshot of attribute table]

Comment: The simplest way is to run a selection query for your four different groups and then hit the Vector - Analysis - Basic Statistics for Fields for each.  You could instead run the Group Stats plugin for a more "elegant" solution or just export the data to a spreadsheet for a pivot table analysis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can categorise your features using a field calculator expression such as this (in this case the output field is called `size_range`):

```sql
case 
    when acres <= 100 then 'lte_100'
    when acres > 100 and acres <= 400 then 'gt_100_and_lte_400'
    when acres > 400 and acres <= 1000 then 'gt_400_and_lte_1000'
    when acres > 1000 then 'gt_1000'
end
```

And then use the *Statistics by categories* tool:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution: array aggregate

Use aggregate function [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg) with a filter, where `area` is the attribute field where the parcel size of each polygon is stored:

```
array_sum (array_agg (area, filter:="area" < 100))
```

---

#### Advanced: all four values at once

To get all four values at once as an array, use this expression:

```
array_foreach(
    array ('<100','>100','>400','>1000'),
    eval ('array_sum (array_agg (area, filter:= area' || @element  || '))')
)
```

*The expression, added with a `round()` function, shows the four sums in the preview:*
[image]